# How to search for flights to "anywhere", if the journey starts and ends in different set of airports?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

Is there a website that allows me to find flights from a set of airports (A/B/C) to ANYWHERE to a different set of airports (X/Y/Z)?

Essentially, I want to go from origin (A/B/C) to destination (X/Y/Z) with a stop somewhere in South Europe. I want the search engine to list me all different possible stops in South Europe (ie. ANYWHERE) so that I could compare the prices.

The closest search engine I found is [kayak nomad](https://kayak.kiwi.com/en/) where I can choose a set of origin airports, a set of destination airports, and ANYWHERE as in between. HOWEVER, it requires AT LEAST TWO between-stops. I want to stay in one place during my trip, not two.

This is what I want to search, BUT I want the destination of the first flight and the origin of the second flight to be the SAME airport ANYWHERE in Europe
[image: example]

**-- Update**

For clarification and more detail:

1. I have a 10-day period (1.-10. Aug.) within which I'd like to travel to South Europe.
2. I'm flexible with the country, as long as it's in South Europe.
3. I'm also flexible with the travel length (5-7 nights) and start/end dates, as long as the travel fits within the 10-day period mentioned previously.
4. I'm also flexible with the origin airports (the journey may start in either TLL or HEL).
5. I'm also flexible with the return airports (the journey may end in TLL or RIX).

Now, given the previously mentioned conditions, I'd like to find all possible travel options and compare them by price.

Does such an advanced flight/travel search engine exists or do I need to try every single possible combination myself?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  When using Multi-city you select your extra cities, so "the two Anywheres" you can choose as the same place

Comment: @Midavalo If I choose the middle city as 'anywhere', then my first flight would be from Helsinki to Italy and second flight from Sweden to Tallinn. But I want it to be from Helsinki to Italy and from Italy to Tallinn. In short the first flight should end in the same airport as the second flight starts from. And I want that option to be 'anywhere

Comment: So do your "Anywhere" search to find your first direct flight, and then do a second search  from that random city to find a flight to your end destination

Comment: @Midavalo not convenient to compare the prices between all possible stopover/layover locations.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I imagine it's about as convenient as the OP is going to get, which is why I made the suggestion.

Comment: Please add a few example _concrete_ itineraries and indicate where are you flexible and where are you not. Until then, this can not be answered. I tried and utterly failed.

Comment: @chx "there is currently no flight search engine that can do what you want" is a legitimate answer

Comment: We have no idea what he wants! Until we do, the question is likely to be closed because of this. He have asked for flights from Northeastern Europe to Southern Europe with a stop in Europe, what does that even mean, if you have two connecting flights quite obviously the connecting airport will be roughly between the two and so it'll be in Europe?? I have no idea what is being asked here.

Comment: You probably want https://azair.eu/

Comment: @chx azair.eu seems to be more functional than some others, but it still doesn't allow for different set of origin and return airports. Also, It's difficult to search a certain region (ie South Europe). Also, as someone who is not good at geography, the listing containing only airport cities and not countries is inconvinient.

Comment: Don't search for a return, search for the individual legs.